# Custom View Controller display

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, uiviewcontroller

I think this could be a simple question but I cannot seem to figure it out.
I have a screen which displays questions from an array. When the array has reached the end I want it to display another VC I have created. With all my other VC they are connected in the storyboard using segues between them. However, I only want this screen to display if I have reached the end of my array? Is what I am trying to doing making sense? Or does anyone know of any useful tutorials I could look at to figure it out for myself?

Comment: When you say "displays questions from an array", do you mean you're displaying questions in a table view, and the array is the data source?

Comment: Yes so I have a plist which has 4 items. These 4 items display in the VC I have already created when a button is pressed. When it reaches the end of the array I have created a vc which just display "level cleared". How do I actually call this view in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can "manually" fire a seque with the **performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:** method using the segue identifier that you set on the segue in the storyboard.  When you call that method the system sets up the right information and then executes **prepareForSegue:sender:** and then actually does the segue -- so the setup looks the same as an automatic segue trigger.
You can "manually" perform any segue with an identifier.

As to creating the segue to perform, you can create a segue from one View Controller to another in the storyboard (i.e. control-drag from the View Controller in the sidebar not from a button or a TableView cell or whatever).  This sort of segue will have to be performed "manually".

Your call to do the "NextVCPlease" segue might look like:

```
if (lastQuestionDone) {
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextVCPlease" sender:whateverMakesSense]
}
```